# OS X ignores alt+3 for #

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, keymap

On my Mac I cannot type the number sign (#) anymore. No matter what application is running alt+3 is no more working. Any ideas how to reactivate it?

Comment: What keyboard layout is configured? Does Keyboard Viewer show `#` on the `3` key when you hold `Option`? What happens when you press `Shift-3`?

Comment: The keyboard loayout is swiss-german. Keyboard Viewer shows # for alt+3. shift+3 gives an * (as it should be). To me everything looks fine, except that I cannot type the # sign.

Comment: Does it work with the other alt key? Does it work on the login window? Does it work (generating any character) when you select a different keyboard layout?

Comment: Did you set any custom keyboard shortcuts, e.g. Switching to a certain space using option + number key? Do other option+number combinations work?

Comment: Does this happen in any application, or only specific ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that the FileExaminer Tool has stolen Alt+3 as a short cut. Uninstalled the tool and rebooted. The Alt+3 give now # as it should. Thanks for the suport.